# Why does mariadb configure with MBCS instead of Unicode on Windows?

Tags: mysql, unicode, cmake, mariadb, mbcs

I am configuring mariadb 10.0.15 on Windows using CMake with the provided defaults.

Why is the libmysql project produced configured to use the Multi-Byte Character Set instead of Unicode?

Comment: What is the reason you ask? Are you missing some functionality that would the there if _UNICODE was defined?

Comment: I wonder if this will have any bearing on the database's ability to work with Unicode strings.

Comment: mysql_options(mysql, MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_NAME, "utf8mb4")  ensures you talk with database unicode (in its UTF8 form), i.e the strings you send need to be UTF8, and the strings you receive are UTF8.  There is no way to work with UTF16 strings, if you wanted that, you need to convert them from/to UTF8